# What causes (javascript library, cms, etc) the "white screen of death" in web browsers?

Tags: css, content-management-system, javascript

I was looking around Stack Overflow for an answer to this problem and found this old question...
[Web Service Call in JavaScript Causing White Screen of Death (WSOD) in Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007577/web-service-call-in-javascript-causing-white-screen-of-death-wsod-in-browser)

With my antiquated Safari web browser I find that I'm experiencing this on a number of websites lately. Here is the list so far:

http://www.treehugger.com/

https://www.udemy.com/

and I believe there was a third that I don't recall.

Basically these sites are completely useless to me. In the case of Udemy I've even tried this on my Nook using the Dolphin web browser and the problem persists. I find it hard to believe that a site like Udemy would be unaware of this continuing problem so I'm wondering what issues there are with my browsers that might lead to this.

Anyway, is there a particular javascript package that these sites may have in common? Any similarities between these two site that anyone can see?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: If your Safari is "antiquated", why haven't you updated it? Also, I tried udemy.com here on my nook, and it came up fine. Perhaps something needs updating there as well? Is Dolphin a browser as well as a file manager?

Comment: I'm on an older Mac that can't be upgraded any further. But the system still works so I keep using it. Which browser did you use on the Nook?

Comment: It's the stock Nook browser. I haven't discovered how to get it to identify itself, but Googling indicates that it's Chrome.